# Android application is not launching when NFC empty tag is detected

Tags: android, nfc

I have a problem detecting empty tags. What i mean with empty tag is a Ndef tag with a record of NdefRecord.TNF_EMPTY type. My application is launched with all tags, but i'm having troubles with this kind of content.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/techlist" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I suppose that techlist is not the problem because Ndef tags are detected correctly, anyway my techlist is this

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
</tech-list>
<tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
</tech-list>
```

"NFC Task Launcher" and "Tags" applications are able to detect this kind of content.

"TagInfo" application detects the tag as NDEF

```
Empty record
type: [NULL]
payload length: 0 bytes
```

Thanks.

Comment: You left out the closing `</resources>` tag in your techlist fragment. But it is present in your techlist xml file, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after many hours testing this problem i've solved it, but i don't know why is this happening.

The problem is with this piece of code in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
   <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/techlist" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've changed it to

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/techlist" />
```

Just taking out the tag "meta-data"  the problem has been solved, but why?

Comment: Because the [definition of `<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) does not allow a `<meta-data>` element.

Comment: Ok, thanks NFC guy, anyway the compiler should say something if meta-data tag is not allowed inside intent-filter.

Comment: May be not directly the compiler, but a Lint warning would have been a valuable hint.